# Almost non-existent training accuracy and low test accuracy

Tags: pytorch, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, multiclass-classification

I am really new to Machine Learning and I am not so well versed in coding in general. However there is need to look through the customers feedback at our store, that average quite a lot each year, yet we cannot tell % of positive, negative and neutral.

Currently I am trying to train a Bert Model to do simple multi labeled sentiment analysis. The input is our store's customers feedback. The customers feedback is not always so clearly defined since customers do tend to tell long and long about their experience and their sentiment is not always so clear. However we managed to get positive, negative and neutral, each set 2247 samples.

But when I try to train it the training accuracy is around 0.4% which is super low. Validation score is around 60%. F1-score is around 60% for each of the label. I wonder what can be done to improve this training accuracy. I have been stuck for a while. Please take a look at my codes and help me out with this.

I have tried changing learning rate (tried all learning rate Bert suggested and 1e-5),changing Max LEN, changing amount of EPOCH, changing drop out rate (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), but so far nothing yielded results.

```
#read dataset
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header=None, names=['content', 'sentiment'], sep='\;', lineterminator='\r',encoding = "ISO-8859-1",engine="python")

from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df = shuffle(df)

df['sentiment'] = df['sentiment'].replace(to_replace = [-1, 0, 1], value = [0, 1, 2])

df.head()

#Load pretrained FinBert model and get bert tokenizer from it
PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME = 'TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

#Choose sequence Length
token_lens = []

for txt in df.content:

 tokens = tokenizer.encode(txt, max_length=512)

 token_lens.append(len(tokens))

sns.distplot(token_lens)

plt.xlim([0, 256]);

plt.xlabel('Token count');

MAX_LEN = 260


#Make a PyTorch dataset
class FIDataset(Dataset):

 def __init__(self, texts, targets, tokenizer, max_len):

   self.texts = texts

   self.targets = targets

   self.tokenizer = tokenizer

   self.max_len = max_len

 def __len__(self):

   return len(self.texts)

 def __getitem__(self, item):

   text = str(self.texts[item])

   target = self.targets[item]

   encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(

     text,

     add_special_tokens=True,

     max_length=self.max_len,

     return_token_type_ids=False,

     pad_to_max_length=True,

     return_attention_mask=True,

     return_tensors='pt',

   )

   return {

     'text': text,

     'input_ids': encoding['input_ids'].flatten(),

     'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].flatten(),

     'targets': torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.long)

   }

#split test and train
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(

 df,

 test_size=0.1,

 random_state=RANDOM_SEED

)

df_val, df_test = train_test_split(

 df_test,

 test_size=0.5,

 random_state=RANDOM_SEED

)

df_train.shape, df_val.shape, df_test.shape

#data loader function
def create_data_loader(df, tokenizer, max_len, batch_size):

 ds = FIDataset(

   texts=df.content.to_numpy(),

   targets=df.sentiment.to_numpy(),

   tokenizer=tokenizer,

   max_len=max_len

 )

 return DataLoader(

   ds,

   batch_size=batch_size,

   num_workers=4

 )

#Load data into train, test, val
BATCH_SIZE = 16

train_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_train, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)

val_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_val, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)

test_data_loader = create_data_loader(df_test, tokenizer, MAX_LEN, BATCH_SIZE)


# Sentiment Classifier based on Bert model just loaded
class SentimentClassifier(nn.Module):

 def __init__(self, n_classes):

   super(SentimentClassifier, self).__init__()

   self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL_NAME)

   self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)

   self.out = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)

 def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
   returned = self.bert(
       
       input_ids=input_ids,
       attention_mask=attention_mask
   )
   pooled_output = returned["pooler_output"]
   output = self.drop(pooled_output)
   
   return self.out(output)


#Create a Classifier instance and move to GPU
model = SentimentClassifier(3)

model = model.to(device)


#Optimize with AdamW
EPOCHS = 5

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr= 2e-5, correct_bias=False)

total_steps = len(train_data_loader) * EPOCHS

scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(

 optimizer,

 num_warmup_steps=0,

 num_training_steps=total_steps

)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)

#Train each Epoch function
def train_epoch(

 model,

 data_loader,

 loss_fn,

 optimizer,

 device,

 scheduler,

 n_examples

):
 
 model = model.train()

 losses = []

 correct_predictions = 0

 for d in data_loader:

   input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)

   attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)

   targets = d["targets"].to(device)

   outputs = model(

     input_ids=input_ids,

     attention_mask=attention_mask

   )

   _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)

   loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)

   correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)

   losses.append(loss.item())

   loss.backward()

   nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)

   optimizer.step()

   scheduler.step()

   optimizer.zero_grad()
   
   return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)

#Eval model function
def eval_model(model, data_loader, loss_fn, device, n_examples):

 model = model.eval()

 losses = []

 correct_predictions = 0

 with torch.no_grad():
       
   torch.cuda.empty_cache()

   for d in data_loader:

     input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)

     attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)

     targets = d["targets"].to(device)

     outputs = model(

       input_ids=input_ids,

       attention_mask=attention_mask

     )

     _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)

     loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)

     correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)

     losses.append(loss.item())
       
   
   
 return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)

#training loop through each epochs

import torch

torch.cuda.empty_cache()

history = defaultdict(list)

best_accuracy = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':  

   for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

     print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')

     print('-' * 10)

     train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(

       model,

       train_data_loader,

       loss_fn,

       optimizer,

       device,

       scheduler,

       len(df_train)

     )

     print(f'Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}')

     val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(

       model,

       val_data_loader,

       loss_fn,

       device,

       len(df_val)

     )

     print(f'Val   loss {val_loss} accuracy {val_acc}')

     print()

     history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)

     history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)

     history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)

     history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

     if val_acc > best_accuracy:

       torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')

       best_accuracy = val_acc
```

-- Edit: I have printed out preds and targets as well as train and val accuracy

[image: training and val accuracy]

Answer (score 2):

Here `_, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)`, you probably want `argmax`, not `max`?

Print out `preds` and `targets` to better see what's going on.

*Edit after preds and targets printed out.* For epochs 4 and 5, `preds` matches `targets` exactly, so train accuracy should be 1. I think the issue is that the accuracy is divided by `n_examples`, which is a number of examples in the whole train dataset, while it should be divided by the number of examples in the epoch.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I have tried argmax but it throws error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). I have edited my first post, printing out preds and targets. Please check.

Comment: @hhp I've updated the answer. Looks like the accuracy is actually good, it's just a bug in how it's computed.

Comment: Hi Sergii, now that you have said I went back to look and indeed the n_examples were len(df_train). Thank you very much for pointing out. However I do wish that my test accuracy could be a bit higher ( I reach 62% the highest for negative label). I am aiming for around 70%. I understand that actually our data set labelling itself is not so accurate (very difficult to go through 2000+ comments about different subjects and label them correctly. Customers tend to mix things in when they give comments.) but how can I improve the F1-score?

Comment: @hhp With the initial accuracy you reported, it was clear there is a bug somewhere. Now it's a completely different question. Maybe the current accuracy it's what should be expected for the task/model/data. Or maybe some hyperparameter tweaking is needed.

Comment: Hi Sergii, I have tried to tweak the Random Seed to higher value and it has yielded 70% overall average accuracy. I have tested with some sentences and it seems to be doing good. Thanks for your help.